# Como baixar uma imagem de uma URL?

Tags: php, imagem

Como faço para baixar uma imagem de uma URL usando o PHP e salvar em uma pasta para usar depois?
Eu desejo salvar imagens do IMDb para usar no meu proprio site.

Primeiramente eu tentei fazer o download da imagem usando a funcao `copy` do PHP
mas nada aconteceu

```
copy($info->Poster, "Posters");
```

`$info->Poster` é o link direto para a imagem.

Comment: Há várias maneiras. o que você já tentou? E tem o lance do site permitir isso também.

Comment: Eu tentei usando a funcao copy, mas nao funcionou, acredito que o download seja permitido sim.

Comment: Adicione sua tentativa na pergunta e exponha melhor o que lhe causou dúvidas.

Comment: Isso não impede sua pergunta de ser responda, mas em princípio você não poderia utilizar essas imagens pois são protegidas por [copyright](http://www.imdb.com/conditions). Isso pode se tornar um problema.

Comment: Eu nao pretendo ganhar dinheiro em cima das imagens ou no site, nao sei se isso faz alguma diferença.. '-

Comment: Claro que faz diferença, é como se "apropriar" de algo que não é seu para seu uso e sem pedir. Mas alem disso, você parece esperar algo pronto, e isso não vai acontecer aqui, se você não expor o que já tentou, dificilmente alguem vai fazer pra você apenas copiar e colar no seu site. Por isso, adicione na pergunta o que você já tentou e seja mais especifico na duvida.

Comment: Eu nao pedi algo pronto, apenas quero uma maneira de resolver isso, algo como simplesmente me mostrar as funcoes que eu poderia usar ja resolveria o meu problema

Comment: Bom, o que posso recomendar é que você pesquise por cURL e como funciona, creio que isso já atenda. Alias, já vi algumas API's open sources que pegam informações do imdb, vale a pena conferir : http://www.omdbapi.com/

Comment: Eu uso uma API, ela me da o link direto da imagem de cada filme ou seriado que pesquiso, com esse link eu gostaria de salvar a imagem em um diretorio do site. Mas fica muito lento ir de um site a outro, eu preciso armazenar os dados no proprio site :/

mas vlw cara, vou pesquisar sobre o cURL

Comment: @Diego, desde que não seja descaradamente ilegal, não é problema nosso  se o código vai infringir algum copyright ou não. Aí já é problema do dono do direito autoral e da pessoa/site que está cometendo a infração.

Comment: Ah, eu nao sabia como exatamente funcionava, vlw ai cara, vou tentar ser mais claro e pesquisar mais. Ei, mas se eu tiver uma duvida, quiser fazer uma coisa e nao saber por onde começar ou o que pesquisar?

Comment: @Naine, se pesquisar no [so], no [pt.so] e no Manual do PHP, já tem vai ter muito código pra testar e novas palavras-chave pra pesquisar. Também pode [pesquisar só dentro de um Stack](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2272/201)  usando o Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro é se certificar que a pasta destino no servidor tem as permissões corretas. Testei com este [código do manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) e funcionou ok, você teria que conferir os logs de erro no seu servidor, mas parece que o código abaixo pode ajudar nisso:

```
<?php
$imgurl = 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTA2MTk3NzI5Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzU2MzYyNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg';
if( !@copy( $imgurl, './teste.jpg' ) ) {
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
} else {
    echo "File copied from remote!";
}
```

Usei o [OMDb API - The Open Movie Database](http://www.omdbapi.com/) para pegar a [URL do poster do filme](http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt2888046).

E testei este outro código, da resposta [*Copy image to my server direct from URL*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6307010/1287812) e funcionou também (atenção para os *paths* e permissões da pasta):

```
function getimg($url) {         
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
    $user_agent = 'php';         
    $process = curl_init($url);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);         
    $return = curl_exec($process);         
    curl_close($process);         
    return $return;     
} 

$imgurl = 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE0NDUzMDcyOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzAxMTA2Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg'; 
$imagename= basename($imgurl);
if(file_exists('./'.$imagename)){continue;} 
$image = getimg($imgurl); 
file_put_contents('./'.$imagename,$image);
```

<sub>Como nota sobre o copyright neste caso, normalmente cartazes de filme são distribuidos livremente pela própria produtora, pelo menos foi assim em todos os longa metragens que estive envolvido e cujo site disponibiliza o cartaz para download.</sub>

Comment: PS: o [Manuel do PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/) é uma mãe, tem que ir sempre lá quando alguma função não faz o esperado ;)